# Get request Activities for strava v3 api python

Tags: python, api, urllib2, urllib

edit - as I couldn't tag this with Strava here are the docs if you're interested - http://strava.github.io/api/

I get through the authentication fine and gain the access_token (and my athlete info) in a response.read.

I'm having problems with the next step:
I want to return information about a specific activity.

```
    import urllib2
    import urllib

    access_token = str(tp[3]) #this comes from the response not shown
    print access_token

    ath_url = 'https://www.strava.com/api/v3/activities/108838256'

    ath_val = values={'access_token':access_token}

    ath_data = urllib.urlencode (ath_val)

    ath_req = urllib2.Request(ath_url, ath_data)

    ath_response = urllib2.urlopen(ath_req)

    the_page = ath_response.read()

    print the_page
```

error is

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\JordanR\Python2.6\documents\strava\auth.py", line 30, in <module>
        ath_response = urllib2.urlopen(ath_req)
      File "C:\Users\JordanR\Python2.6\lib\urllib2.py", line 124, in urlopen
        return _opener.open(url, data, timeout)
      File "C:\Users\JordanR\Python2.6\lib\urllib2.py", line 389, in open
        response = meth(req, response)
      File "C:\Users\JordanR\Python2.6\lib\urllib2.py", line 502, in http_response
        'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
      File "C:\Users\JordanR\Python2.6\lib\urllib2.py", line 427, in error
        return self._call_chain(*args)
      File "C:\Users\JordanR\Python2.6\lib\urllib2.py", line 361, in _call_chain
        result = func(*args)
      File "C:\Users\JordanR\Python2.6\lib\urllib2.py", line 510, in http_error_default
        raise HTTPError(req.get_full_url(), code, msg, hdrs, fp)
    HTTPError: HTTP Error 404: Not Found
```

the 404 is a puzzle as I know this activity exists?

Is 'access_token' the correct header information?
the documentation (http://strava.github.io/api/v3/activities/#get-details) uses Authorization: Bearer ?  I'm not sure how liburl would encode the Bearer part of the info?

sorry if some of my terminology is a bit off, I'm new to this.

answered this bad boy.

```
import requests as r
access_token = tp[3]

ath_url = 'https://www.strava.com/api/v3/activities/108838256'
header = {'Authorization': 'Bearer 4b1d12006c51b685fd1a260490_example_jklfds'}

data = r.get(ath_url, headers=header).json()
```

it needed the "Bearer" part adding in the Dict.

thanks for the help idClark

Comment: I too am having trouble making sense of the Bearer param. Have you tried hitting the endpoint from the command line? If I do `curl -XGET https://www.strava.com/api/v3/activities/111008284 -H "Authorization: Bearer my_access_token_goes_here" | jq '.'` I can get back the JSON just fine. I'll try with Python later.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I prefer using the third-party [Requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) module. You do indeed need to follow the documentation and use the Authorization: Header documented in [the API](http://strava.github.io/api/v3/activities/#get-details)

Requests [has an arg for header data](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/api/). We can then create a dict where the key is `Authorization` and its value is a single string `Bearer access_token`

```
#install requests from pip if you want
import requests as r
url = 'https://www.strava.com/api/v3/activities/108838256'
header = {'Authorization': 'Bearer access_token'}
r.get(url, headers=header).json()
```

If you really want to use urllib2

```
#using urllib2
import urllib2
req = urllib.Request(url)
req.add_header('Authorization', 'Bearer access_token')
resp = urllib2.urlopen(req)
content = resp.read()
```

Just remember `access_token` needs to be the literal string value, eg acc09cds09c097d9c097v9

Comment: thanks @idclark for looking at this.  I've had a go with requests and failed, I did get a json response, so some success, although it told me authorization had failed.  Is this a silly question, on the header line should the "Bearer access_token" be my literal string value?

Comment: amended in the question.